# chemmacros reaction environment align

Tags: align, chemmacros

Take the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\begin{reactions*}
NH3 + H2O &<=> NH4+ + OH-\\
Fe^3+ + 3 OH- &-> Fe(OH)3\\
2 Fe(OH)3   &->[heat] Fe2O3 + 3 H2O
\end{reactions*}
\begin{reactions*}
G &-> H + I \\
J + K &-> L
\end{reactions*}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrow misalign]

The first reaction scheme has two different arrow types and alignment only on start of arrow. Ideally I want the LHS ( r) aligned (as it is), the arrows ( c) aligned and the RHS (l ) aligned as it is in the first two lines and the second reaction scheme.

I have tried putting an `&` after the arrows to align the products side but to no avail. Outside of placing it within an `align` or `tabular` environment and encapsulating each segment in `\ch{ }` is there an alternative?

ps I used `\documentclass{article}` as `minimal` or `standalone` classes have an issue with `chemmacros` but that's for another day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I propose something else?

I would not tweak around with the alignments but try to get the arrows all to the same length. The two extreme versions would look like in my MWE. You can, of course, try to find some pleasing middle between those.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
    \begin{reactions*}
        NH3 + H2O &<=> NH4+ + OH-\\
        Fe^3+ + 3 OH- &-> Fe(OH)3\\
        2 Fe(OH)3   &->[\makebox[0pt]{heat}] Fe2O3 + 3 H2O
    \end{reactions*}
    \begin{reactions*}
        NH3 + H2O &<=>[\phantom{heat}] NH4+ + OH-\\
        Fe^3+ + 3 OH- &->[\phantom{heat}] Fe(OH)3\\
        2 Fe(OH)3   &->[heat] Fe2O3 + 3 H2O
    \end{reactions*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to align the terms as you have written in your post, you could do this within an `array` environment. You could define your custom column types or just write them into the `\begin{array}{...}` declaration:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ch}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{}>{\collectcell\ch}c<{\endcollectcell}@{}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\ch}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{array}{R C L}
    NH3 + H2O &<=> &NH4+ + OH-\\[\jot] % or any other measure. The screen shot below is showing [0pt]
    Fe^3+ + 3 OH- &-> &Fe(OH)3\\[\jot]
    2 Fe(OH)3   &->[heat] &Fe2O3 + 3 H2O
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. As you point out it is to do with the arrow lengths. I have upvoted this answer. I'll wait a while before I accept it to see if any other different solutions are suggested.